# How to get Object field from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here i want to get WorkStatus of attendance from 0th index, but below code shows tha whole attendance array with multiple array of object. how i get attendance's single object{},from array of objects[]..

```
const abc = await Attendance.find({ "attendance.WorkStatus": "P" });
```

Output:

```
{
    date: '2022-02-15',
    attendance: [[Object], [Object], [Object],[Object], [Object], [Object],[Object],
],}
```

Comment: I think `[Object]` is not the best way to know what fields object has.

Comment: `output.attendance[0].WorkStatus`?

Comment: Can you show the fields inside the attendance array?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the fields inside the attendance array. But it shows {[object] inside the attendance array.